# How to stop loading data from realtime database before the start of the activity?

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I know that the realtime database is of asynchronous type. But is there any way to stop loading data before the start of the activity. I have lot of data that these activities loads, which is not required. I want to decrease the usage of loading realtime database data. Even if I am wrong please correct me.

This is the code:-

```
class Profile : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile)

        findViewById<TextView>(R.id.sign_out_btn).setOnClickListener {
            Firebase.auth.signOut()
            val intent = Intent(this, ELogIn::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }

        findViewById<Button>(R.id.Edit_details_button).setOnClickListener {
            val eDetails = Intent(this, EDetailsForm::class.java)
            eDetails.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
            eDetails.putExtra("user", "old")
            startActivity(eDetails)
        }


        val currentUserId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!.uid

        val userRef =
            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("Users").child(currentUserId)
        userRef.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                    profile_layout.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    val userData = dataSnapshot.getValue(ProfileModel::class.java)

                    Picasso.get().load(userData!!.getImageUrl())
                        .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_baseline_image_200).into(profile_image)
                    profile_name.text = userData.getname()
                }
            }

            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {

            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Since you did not post any code I will say that by commenting out the code that loads the data will stop the data being loaded.

Comment: I have added the code. Can you help me with this code. Other codes are also similar.

Comment: You can start the load in `onStart` where the screen gets visible to the user or in any other appropriate lifecycle event or use some sort of conditioning on when the data should be loaded & when not.

Comment: I have tried it onStart, onResume, and countdown timer as well.

Comment: After opening the app, I let some data load of first activity, then I turned off data, then went to other activity. After the activity is started, The countdown timer starts. After the timer is over the data starts loading and I got the data. So, the data is already downloaded but is shown only after timer is over irrespective of the data is on or off.

Comment: 1) If you don't want to load data, don't call `addValueEventListener`. 2) If the code you shared is loading more data than you want it to load, which data is that? Can you show us the JSON of your database that you want it to load and that you don't want it to load (as text, no screenshots please)? You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: What is an alternative for `addValueEventListener`. I want to load all the data only after the activity is started. There is no data that I don't want to load.

Comment: May be you can try single Value event listener.. it's one time listener...

Comment: single value event listener not working

Comment: I think that a splash screen will solve the issue, right?

Comment: How can I do this?